# Getting words out of a text file with C#

Tags: c#, text-files, ienumerable, yield-return

I have write a method that gets words that start with a "b" out of a randomtext file and return a IEnumerable. It has to work with a yield return.

The problem is that i don't know how to write such a method in combination with Ienumerable and yield return.

this is what i got so far:
GetWords.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace week3
         {
             class GetWords : IEnumerable<String>
    {

        private String[] getWords;

        public GetWords()
        {

        }

        public IEnumerator<String> GetEnumerator()
        {
            try
            {
                String path = @"C:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\randomtext.txt";
                foreach (String word in getWords (path, s => s.StartsWith("b")))
                 Console.Write("{0}; ", word);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("wrong path");

            }
            yield return word;
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the problems I guess.

Comment: you need to declare and initialize your variable `word` outside try block to return it outside try block.

Comment: why the need of `yield`? With `LINQ` you can just return the `.Where()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this method yield returns all words, that start with a 'b'

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadWords(this FileInfo fileInfo, Encoding enc)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            do
            {
                string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                foreach (string word in line)
                {
                    if (word.StartsWith('b'))
                    yield return word;
                }

            } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\randomtext.txt";
var result = ReadWords(path, Encoding.Default);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line would do the task and uses yield return internally:

```
var allWordsStartingWithB = File.ReadLines(filePath).SelectMany(line => line.Split(' ')).Where(word => word.StartsWith("b"));
```

Of course you can do use yield return more explicitly if you want like this, although this is sort of useless:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadWordsStartingWithB(string filePath)
{
    var allWordsStartingWithB = File.ReadLines(filePath).SelectMany(line => line.Split(' ')).Where(word => word.StartsWith("b"));
    foreach(var wordWithB in allWordsStartingWithB)
        yield return wordWithB;
}
```

Unlike the *ReadAllText* method *ReadLines* also returns an IEnumerable. The advantage: The method does not read the whole file unless it needs to. So if you just want the first 5 words that start with a **b** you could do it like this and only the needed lines of the file would be read instead of the whole one:

```
var first5Words = ReadWordsStartingWithB("\folder\subfolder\textFile.txt").Take(5).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use system.io.file.readalltext to get all the text. 
Split it by " " to get the words. 
Then just look for anything that starts with a b:

```
var wordsThatStartWithB = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\\test.txt")
        .Split(char.Parse(" "))
        .Where(x => x.StartsWith("b"));
```

Comment: Why to use `char.Parse(" ")`? Just use single quotes to define a `char`: ie. `' '`.